# Resource File vs Static Class for values that will not need to be localized in C#

Tags: c#

I overheard two of my coworkers debating this topic and I was wondering what the general thought is.

Right now in our application we use a lot of key value pairs and they are looking for the best way to implement a solution that would avoid us to remember the spelling for the key.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A resource file generates static class behind the scenes to access those resources so you end up basically with the same thing. It's just that if you use a resource file and one day you decide to localize you are good to go. Of course there is no definite answer to this question. Looks subjective to me as both solutions are perfectly viable.

Comment: Yea thats what i figured. I know they both do basically the same thing, I was just wondering what most people would use given the choice...